# Recovering an APK's code

Tags: android, apk

I recently erased my hard drive and lost few weeks of work. Despite committing frequently, I hadn't pushed my changes upstream for a while.

I've extracted my app's APK from my phone and I've been trying to recover its code. I'm assuming it's possible since it was a test build (and, consequently, not obfuscated or anything like that).

The best result I was able to achieve was by using [dex2jar](http://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) but I still have a lot of code like this:

```
int i = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(2131165184);
int j = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(2131165184);
screenNameParams.addRule(10);
screenNameParams.addRule(1, 2131034138);
screenNameParams.setMargins(paramInt, 0, 0, 0);
```

Or even:

```
long l1 = paramLong1;
long l2 = paramLong2;
long l3 = paramLong3;
int i = paramInt;
List localList = localClient.getBetween(l1, l2, l3, i);
```

My experience with [android-apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) was even worse, since I wasn't even able to get some Java code out of it... which is expected, since it works with smali debugging.

I've read all related questions here on SO and I've seen people saying that "it is tough to get the actual source code for the apk unless you're the developer", so there's hope since I'm the developer.

Finally, my question is: *Is it possible to fully recover an APK's original code, considering it was a test build from eclipse?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no. It looks like your code was run through ProGuard and obfuscated (as is normal) and so you won't be able to get your original code. In your quote about being the developer, those people are basically saying "it's hard to get the source for an APK unless you already have it because you're the developer" but in this case even though you're the developer, you've lost the source.

The only last option I can think of that you might try is to find a hard drive recovery program and use it as soon as possible and see if you can recover your source. Maybe you haven't overwritten those sectors yet.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is ProGuard bundled with the ADT? I never installed nor configured it myself.

Comment: Yes, it's included as part of the Android build system: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

Comment: @JaVAndroid did you read the original question and my answer? He knows how to get the APK and decompile. The problem is that it's obfuscated.